# How to separate 'Implemented Conditional Validation Service/Function' in Angular-8 while using Reactive-Forms

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation, angular-custom-validators

I have implemented conditional Validation in my Component.
I am trying to separate the validation logic from my component to another component/service.

Demo Link : http://StackBlitz%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amr86r

Answer (score 1):

You can easily apply conditional validation using **`@rxweb/reactive-form-validators`**. I have applied required validation through both validator as well as decorator based approach. Please refer to the [working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xppztx?file=src/app/decorator-based.component.html) example.

**Using Decorator based approach:**

You just need to apply `@required()` decorator with the condition you want to apply on your model-property.

Here is the complete model code:

```
import {  required } from   "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators"   

export class UserInfo {

    @required() 
    firstName: string;

    @required({conditionalExpression:'x => x.firstName == "Bharat"' }) 
    lastName: string;

}
```

**Using Validator based approach:**

For validator based approach, you just need to mention `RxwebValidators.required()` with the condition you want to apply on your form-control.

Here is the complete component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms"
import { RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-validator-based-validator',
    templateUrl: './validator-based.component.html'
})
export class ValidatorBasedValidationComponent implements OnInit {
    validatorBasedFormGroup: FormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder )
    { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.validatorBasedFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            firstName:['', RxwebValidators.required()],
            lastName:['', RxwebValidators.required({conditionalExpression:'x => x.firstName == "Bharat"' })]
        });
    }
}
```

Note : if you will use validator approach then, You can create a function in a separate file and use that respective function in the condtional expression property. In anyway, the model file will be separated in decorator based approach.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement and see which of the two goes better for my case and give a proper feedback.